# How to reconfigure the SSL/TSL version to 1.2 for the SAP BO application using Java version 1.8

Tags: networking, ssl, tomcat, java

We have SSL configured for our BO application:Version 4.1 SP 10, Tomcat version :1.8

In the server.xml file, the config is as

Which version of SSL is used here and if it is using SSL 1.0 and 1.1 we need to change it to 1.2.

OS level changes are already done.

Comment: You didn't add your `server.xml`. Your JRE version might also have an influence.

Comment: <Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" connectionTimeout="20000" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true" clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" keystorePass="xxx" keystoreFile="xxx" maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="25" acceptCount="100" enableLookups="false"/>

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming, you are using Tomcat 8.5. This version can use three kinds of connectors for `HTTP/1.1`: `Http11NioProtocol` and `Http11Nio2Protocol`, which can use keystores and both **JSSE** and **OpenSSL** as SSL implementations and the faster `Http11AprProtocol`, which uses **OpenSSL**.

The default connector is detected based on whether **libtcnative** can be found on the system. Your implementation is probably NIO, since it accepts keystores. Also the SSL implementation is probably `JSSEImplementation`. This limits you to **TLSv1.2**, since Java 8 does not support TLSv1.3.

You should change your connector configuration to the following (defaults omitted):

```
<Connector port="8443" SSLEnabled="true"
  scheme="https" secure="true" maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="25">
    <SSLHostConfig protocols="TLSv1.2,TLSv1.3" sslProtocol="TLSv1.2">
        <Certificate certificateKeystoreFile="xxx"
          certificateKeystorePassword="xxx"/>
    </SSLHostConfig>
</Connector>
```

Remark that since Tomcat 8.5, specifying the keystore on the `<Connector>` element works, but is deprecated. You should use `<SSLHostConfig>` as above.

**PS:** If I remember correctly SSLv3 is disabled by default on Java 8, so you don't need to worry about that.